# 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: jboss

I got the following error while starting JBoss from a command line prompt today:

```
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: I got this issue when using `findstr` in a cmd batch script. I think because of the `setlocal` command at the beginning of the script. To solve the problem I just placed the exact path `"C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe"` instead.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Please google it, you can find a lot of answers. But do as below to fix it. Add the following value to  Right Click My Compuer -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Select Path variable -> append the below value.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32

It should work with that change.

Comment: Pretty funny how you said "Please google it" because now this is the #1 result for "findstr is not recognized". :-P

Comment: Yes, but this is only a workaround. See my answer on how to fix the PATH variable.

Comment: After you add the PATH variable, you may be required to restart your application for the settings to take effect.

Comment: @StephenWylie Thank you :)

Comment: A neater way to specify the path is to use %systemroot%\system32

Comment: That happens because on Windows 10 the PATH doesn't have anymore reference to sys32 but Wildfly is using .bat to run on Windows

Comment: I checked my PATH variable and this is already in it, however I still see this error.

Comment: Remember to close and open VS code after adding the variable...

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32 does not exist !

Comment: @javaauthority you're right. Restarting the application made the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed, issue is in wrong settings of PATH variable in Windows.
According to [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/63b84992-3814-4c00-acbf-fc09816570e5/problem-in-path-settings-windows7) this is most probably because some stupid installer wrongly modified PATH variable in Windows registry. Registry has 2 different string value types - `REG_SZ` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. Only the second one allows for expansion of `%SystemRoot%`.

So check your path by typing `set path` in command prompt. If you see unexpanded `%SystemRoot%` and other variables in Path, you are affected (PATH should show only plain directory names, not variables).

You need to edit Path variable in registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. As it is not possible to change the type of key, save the path value somewhere, delete the key and re-create it with type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. You need to logout for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

for me it works when I've coped findstr(from windows/system32) to wildfly/bin

Answer (score 2):

Please go throught the simplest steps:-

1. go to `C:\Windows\system32\` and copy `findstr.exe` file.
2. paste this file into the location `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin`
3. Run your jboss again you will get out of this.....

Comment: @AshuPhaugat just because it works doesn't mean it's the right way to do things. This is how we end up with bloated/broken software.

Answer (score 2):

You can also hard code the directory by replacing 'findstr' with 'C:\Windows\system32\findstr'. This is useful when using systems with restricted user permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you %SystemRoot% is evaluating (type set path into a command prompt, you should not see %SystemRoot%, but instead that actual path). If your path variable's (user, or systems) first entry begins with an %(an environment variable) this can cause an issue.

To resolve this, simply swap this first entry with anything else in your path that does not lead with an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

For IBM ACE solution for

'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

1. Go to the path C:\Windows\System32
2. Find the findstr.exe, copy it and then find the path where you bin file of your application is found. eg C:\Program Files\IBM\ACE\11.0.0.12\server\bin   then past it inside the bin file
3. cancel the console of ace and re-open it.
4. Then run ACE toolkit command on ace console.
5. Then press enter, now it can open.

Answer (score 0):

I have try to work with play framework but stuck with to run activator.bat file but solution is the same just copy file from windows/system32/findsr and past it to under stuck folder then run the respective file again.
thanks to andrewsiand Suryaprakash

Answer (score 0):

Please beware that current Windows systems use a Capital "S" for the System directory, so:
C:\WINDOWS\System32
%SystemRoot%\System32

Omitting the capital S will result in a neglect of the line in the %PATH%

Comment: Which Windows version has by default case sensitive NTFS filesystem for system drive?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (not JBoss related) the following helped to fixed this error.

Instead of:

```
SET path="%path%;C:\some\additional\path"
```

I used:

```
SET "path=%path%;C:\some\additional\path"
```