# I am getting the below error while starting hybrisserver.bat

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Usage: "G:\HybrisPendrive\Hybris\hybris\bin\platform\tomcat\bin\wrapper.bat" { console : start : pause : resume : stop : restart : install : remove : update } You can give _YWRAPPER_CONF as env. variable to set the path of the used wrapper configuration file. Defaults to '..\conf\wrapper.conf'.

Comment: what is the language of your computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244181/findstr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score -1):

You are probably missing system32 in your PATH variable. Try adding C:\Windows\System32 to your path variable. Info how to do this: [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Good luck