# Unable to launch JMeter on Windows

Tags: java, jmeter

I am unable to launch Apache JMeter on Windows. Double clicking on the batch file results in the following error:

> 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command,operable program or batch file. not able to find java
>   executable or version. errorlevel=2

Comment: do you have java installed properly, in example can you retrieve "java -version" via commandline?

Comment: You say "not able to find java executable or version". Jmeter does not run without java. Did you install it correctly and can you call ``java -version`` in your shell?

Comment: Install java https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml

Comment: Yes I have installed java..command prompt shows 1.7.0_25 as java version

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244181/findstr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Double click on ApacheJmeter.jar file to open JMeter. If you want the console window, you need to open jmeter.bat file by configuring environment variables. Also, use latest version of jmeter.

Answer (score -1):

Copy over the executable `findstr.exe` from `C:\Windows\System32\` to the directory where you are calling JMETER batch script from. Alternately set your `PATH` system variable to `C:\Windows\System32\`.

Comment: Downvoter, did you downvote it because it didn't work for you? Can you specify what error you are getting? Blindly downvoting an an answer won't help you or the answerer or the future readers.