# How to install solr-6.6.0 in windows 7

Tags: java, windows, solr

I am trying to install `solr-6.6.0` in windows but unable to do this. To install it I installed java (jdk1.8.0_131). But still i am not able to figure out what went wrong.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Something is missing.  Please list all steps you took when installing Java.

Comment: I think cmd is not able to recognized the '**findstr**' command. Follow this steps to set up path for above command https://stackoverflow.com/a/10246879/3593530 and I guess it will work.

Comment: @sanjay .. I am following the same path to get findstr.exe. copied from windows/system32 and paste in respective directry. But still unable to run solr.

Comment: @Andersen I downloaded jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe and installed it simply by clicking on it. My programmes in eclipse running fine . I have both java 7 and 8 in my system but I Installed 8 latter. One thing may you have look I set JAVA_Home system variable with path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131"   is it right??

Comment: Well there must be some path problem. You can set java home manually in Solr. Set `SOLR_JAVA_HOME=<PATH\TO\YOUR\JAVA\DIR>` in **solr.in.cmd**.

Comment: Please suggest your steps to install solr and how to set JAVA_HOME system variable. May be it can be possible that I was following wrong steps.

Comment: @sanjay  I did it, SOLR_JAVA_HOME=<PATH\TO\YOUR\JAVA\DIR> in solr.in.cmd. SOLR_JAVA_HOME path was missing in solr.in.cmd. But still getting same problem. May now, I need to remove JAVA_HOME variable from system variable.?? please suggest.

Comment: Hit the command `bin/solr start` from solr home directory. (i.e. from solr-6.6.0 folder try that command. )

Comment: @vinod .. I was doing same .. you can check it out in attached screen shot while question being asked.

Comment: I saw thats why I mentioned to go back one directory.  you did `cd solr-6.6.0/bin` am saying just `cd solr-6.6.0` and run the command bin/solr start

Comment: okk..  But I think there was error in downloaded zip file of solr-6.6.0 because when i tried solr-6.1.0  to install, it got installed very easily following the same steps. so as of now I am ok with that. thanks for assistance.