# Having an issue while installing jmeter.bat file in jmeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter

Having an issue while installing jmeter.bat file in jmeter 4.0.I have installed jdk 8. I am getting the below error when i open the jmeter.bat file.

```
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
```

Comment: Install Java correctly and then retry installing jmeter

Comment: I have installed correctly. when I typed and check java -version **java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)**

Comment: Did you try to launch the Jmeter.bat file and see it works ?

Comment: Please start with a Google of the message. First response: -> Do this -> Right click My Compuer -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Select Path variable -> append "C:\WINDOWS\system32".

Comment: Source:1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244181/findstr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command 2) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/findstr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or/87f77967-538c-4a77-a9d8-917b6e577a84

Answer (score 0):

You probably removed `C:\Windows\System32` folder from your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), you can add it back as

```
set PATH=%SYSTEM32%;c:\java\bin;%PATH%
```

change this `c:\java` to the real path of your JDK or JRE installation, once done you should be able to execute JMeter from that cmd or powershell window.

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) (or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version which is available at [Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page), now it seems to be just right moment for this